# SELECT * ... WHERE col="string" returns invalid row

Tags: sqlite

I'm getting a confusing select...where result, the table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE modes (
               key INTEGER,
               mode INTEGER,
               channel INTEGER,
               name TEXT,
               short_name TEXT,
               def INTEGER,
               highlight INTEGER,
               catagory TEXT,
               subcatagory TEXT);
```

It's populated with:

```
sqlite> select * from modes;
  3|6|5|Green|G|0|255|a|b
  3|6|6|Blue|B|0|255|a|b
  3|9|1|Mode|Mode|0|255|a|b
  3|9|2|Auto Mode Speed|Speed|0|255|a|b
  3|9|3|Strobe|Strobe|0|255|a|b
  3|9|4|Red|R|0|255|a|b
  3|9|5|Green|G|0|255|a|b
  3|9|6|Blue|B|0|255|a|b
  3|9|7|Red2|R2|0|255|a|b
  3|9|8|Green2|G2|0|255|a|b
  3|9|9|Blue2|B2|0|255|a|b
  3|6|4|Red|R|0|255|a|b
  3|6|1|6|6|0|255|a|b
  3|6|2|Auto mode speed|speed|0|255|a|b
  3|6|3|Strobe|Strobe|0|255|strobe|b
```

Note the row 3rd from the bottom:
    **3|6|1|6|6|0|255|a|b**

If I do a select:
    `SELECT * FROM modes where mode=6 and name="Mode" order by channel;`

It returns:
    `3|6|1|6|6|0|255|a|b`

Columns 4 and 5 (name and short_name) should not match, they are 6 and the match term is "Mode".  If I change the match string "Mode" to any other string it works as expected.  Is "Mode" a reserved word? or Did I somehow set a variable "Mode" to 6?.  I don't understand this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ["] it means columns, so when you do

```
name="Mode"
```

it means you search in column name that have same value as column Mode. So you select where mode=6 and name=6 actually on your code.
If you want to use string, use ['] not ["]

I try to use that code on my database..

```
select * from products
where name="Mode"
```

And I got error

```
ERROR:  column "Mode" does not exist
LINE 2: where name="Mode"
```

Comment: If you want to give a condition with string just try using LIKE or else, not [=].

Comment: Thank you, that change makes it behave as expected. 
I found the single quote in the docs, I'm still looking for the double quote.
I tried to vote you up but I don't have enough Reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it in the docs if anyone else is looking.
it's in the [the sqlite3 FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q24)

Answer (score 0):

My familiarity is not with sqlite3, but I would say that it looks to me like you are doing name="Mode" which is taking the modes.mode object and checking it.

If you do `SELECT * FROM modes where name="Mode" order by channel`. You may find that it just gives you `3|6|1|6|6|0|255|a|b` as well.